# Tracing recursive path in Towers of Hanoi

Tags: java, recursion, stack

Can you explain me the procedure to trace the recursive steps in Towers of Hanoi problem using stacks? You can find the java code in this website:

http://www.javawithus.com/programs/towers-of-hanoi

The recursive program for the puzzle in Java is given below:

```
public class TowersOfHanoi {

   public void solve(int n, String start, String auxiliary, String end) {
       if (n == 1) {
           System.out.println(start + " -> " + end);
       } else {
           solve(n - 1, start, end, auxiliary);
           System.out.println(start + " -> " + end);
           solve(n - 1, auxiliary, start, end);
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       TowersOfHanoi towersOfHanoi = new TowersOfHanoi();
       System.out.print("Enter number of discs: ");
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int discs = scanner.nextInt();
       towersOfHanoi.solve(discs, "A", "B", "C");
   }
}
```

Any other supplement materials to understand recursion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just showing a link is not good (content may change etc). Furthermore, this is a little broad-asked. My simple answer would be: debug the program. Have fun!

Comment: It calls the function `solve()` until the tower doesn't have just one disk. After that, the values (here disks) are being replaced with the auxiliary values.